# Error building Ionic app: Failed to execute aapt (CordovaLib:processDebugResources)

Tags: android, linux, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use Ionic framework to build hybrid mobile apps but I'm facing the following problem since a few days.

When I want to build the application (which is actually a blank project), the command "**`ionic cordova build android`**" returns this error (detailed logs below) when executing `CordovaLib:processDebugResources` task:

> /home/pi/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")

I tried to reinstall many times Android SDK. I also tried different versions of Android tools/platforms (23, 26) but it did nothing.

I didn't find on the web any solution to solve this problem.
So, if someone has an idea or already faced this problem and solved it, do not hesitate!

- Detailled logs when building the app:

> :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> :CordovaLib:processDebugResources/home/pi/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt:
> 2:
> /home/pi/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")
>
> ```
>       FAILED
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     * What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>     > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     * Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     BUILD FAILED
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     Total time: 55.363 secs
>     Error: /home/pi/IonicPJ/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>     Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
>     /home/pi/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: 2: /home/pi/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: Syntax error:
>     newline unexpected (expecting ")")
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>     * What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>     > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> ```

- You will find below different element concerning the components installed.

  ```
  Ionic 3.8.1
  Cordova 7.0.1
  Gradle 4.1
  JAVA 8
  ```

I set the variables `$JAVA_HOME`, `$ANDROID_HOME` and added `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to `$PATH` variable

This is the packages I installed via Android `SDKManager`:

```
    Installed packages:
  Path                        | Version | Description                    | Location
  -------                     | ------- | -------                        | -------
  build-tools;23.0.1          | 23.0.1  | Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 | build-tools/23.0.1/
  emulator                    | 26.1.3  | Android Emulator               | emulator/
  extras;android;m2repository | 47.0.0  | Android Support Repository     | extras/android/m2repository/
  extras;google;m2repository  | 57      | Google Repository              | extras/google/m2repository/
  patcher;v4                  | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher/v4/
  platform-tools              | 26.0.0  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/
  platforms;android-23        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 23        | platforms/android-23/
  platforms;android-25        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 25        | platforms/android-25/
  tools                       | 26.0.2  | Android SDK Tools              | tools/
```

When I run "**`ionic cordova platform ls`**", I have:

```
Installed platforms:
android 6.2.3
```

And everything is running on a raspberry with Raspbian Jessie:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Same problem, did you get any solution?

Comment: Posible reason SDK not installed properly. Try reinstall SDK 23 again.

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced this issue, This issue occurred when I've added allowClearTextTraffic in config.xml for fixing the clear text issue. I've fixed the cleartext issue in another way and then run

`ionic cordova resources android`

Then the build issue was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

There is some configuration issue with the setup of these variables.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/username/Android/Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/username/Android/Sdk
PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/29.0.2/
```

> You can do a build using android studio instead of ionic CLI.